# IOS App should not be killed in background state

Tags: android, ios, react-native, timer, background-service

I am trying to understand, is there any way to develop ReactNative app with following conditions:

1. In this application timer will be run in the background state.
2. This application should not be killable in the background state.

In android background timer is work perfect but in IOS when app is in background state since 30 seconds then app is killed in background state.

I used 'react-native-background-timer' package for timer.

Please help me to run background timer in IOS for more than 30 seconds or some minutes.
Thanks.

Comment: The app is killed because it might be using too much CPU in the background and to save memory iOS killed it. You should find another way to deal with whatever you are trying to achieve because the user could disable background refresh which I think will disable 30 seconds timer as well.

Comment: Thanks for update @SaachiTech. Can you please suggest me the better way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need to use a background timer? Can't you accomplish the task without it? Please explain the scenario and app code so we can evaluate. Thanks

Comment: I develop app which include main workout, set and rest timer. When user start the workout main workout and set timer will be start. When set timer will finish then automatic render rest timer screen so this scenario is perfect work in foreground.

Requirements are when app is in background state then this flow should be work as foreground.

Comment: I don’t think you need a background operation here. I think you can achieve this by using app state and timers. So as soon the application state set to background, save current time and as soon it become active check last saved time against current time and render view.

Comment: Yes you are right but assume that user select 10 seconds for one set and app is in background state. Now user reopen app after 50 seconds or more so there is more confusing to handle number of sets and rest time and render view after reopen app.